# Next-auth runs on every request in preview

Tags: next.js, vercel, next-auth

I'm facing a very strange issue with next-auth.

We have a next.js app deployed on Vercel.
Some of our API endpoints require authentication, and some don't.

Locally, everything works fine, but in preview, next-auth runs on every request. So when for instance a new user makes a request to sign up, next-auth runs, tries to authenticate the user by email and password and throws an error because can't authenticate the user.

Even if I comment the throw error and return a 200 status code inside the getUserByEmailAndPassword function, the request doesn't go the the signup API at all.
Although in the browser I can see the request direct to the right API endpoint, the handler for that API doesn't run at all.
I only receive response from next-auth

I tried to change the NEXTAUTH_URL environmental variable to match the url for the current preview, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

I found out this was happening because I was importing the same instance of next-connect

https://github.com/hoangvvo/next-connect/issues/141